# chrome://plugins site cannot be reached

Tags: flash, chromium

I am newbie to Ubuntu .I have recently installed Chromium and whenever I try to open Zynga Poker , it says allow flash player. now I have seen some some methods which guided me to enable flash player by opening chrome://plugins. but whenever I try to open it , it says site cannot be reached. Please help me out to use flash player in site and open plugins website.

[image: Screenshot :]

Comment: Outdated info, open this instead: chrome://settings/content/flash

Comment: @AlexK. did not worked. it opens settings only.